# How to declare the second parameter type in the assign operation in typescript

Tags: typescript

```js
interface Person {
  name: string,
  age: number,
  height: number,
}

const bob: Person = {
  name: 'bob',
  age: 25,
  height: 170
}

// How to declare the second parameter (info) type if I don't want to use 'any' 
const updatePerson: (person: Person, info: any) => void = (person, info) => {
 Object.assign(person, info)
} 

updatePerson(bob, {height: 180})
console.log(bob) // { name: 'bob', age: 25, height: 180 }
updatePerson(bob, {age: 26})
console.log(bob) // { name: 'bob', age: 26, height: 180 }
```

As you can see, the second parameter ‘info’ may contain some attributes of the Person type, so how do I define its type?

My initial idea was to use the type assertion "info as Person", but it doesn't seem to be the best solution, but to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) for `info` param.

> Constructs a type with all properties of Type set to optional. This utility will return a type that represents all subsets of a given type.

```
const updatePerson: (person: Person, info: Partial<Person>) => Person = (person, info) => {
  return Object.assign(person, info)
}
```

Comment: Wow! The reply was too fast, and it completely solved my problem,Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can Use That Info also as Person but need TO modify Your Code Like This
Make the model values are optional

```
interface Person {
  name?: string,
  age?: number,
  height?: number,
}

const bob: Person = {
  name: 'bob',
  age: 25,
  height: 170
}

// How to declare the second parameter (info) type if I don't want to use 'any' 
const updatePerson: (person: Person, info: Person ) => void = (person, info) => {
 Object.assign(person, info)
} 

updatePerson(bob, {height: 180})
console.log(bob) // { name: 'bob', age: 25, height: 180 }
updatePerson(bob, {age: 26})
console.log(bob) // { name: 'bob', age: 26, height: 180 }
```